# How to integrate Lottie Interactivity with Svelte

Tags: svelte, lottie

I'm trying to integrate [Lottie Interactivity](https://github.com/LottieFiles/lottie-interactivity) into my Svelte code. Unfortunately, out-of-the-box it throws error codes.

When you dig into their [docs](https://docs.lottiefiles.com/lottie-interactivity/), they provide hooks for React and Vue — but no Svelte!

I'm still relatively new with Svelte, so if people can even provide pointers as to how to *get started* with integrating this into Svelte, I would greatly appreciate this!

(And before anyone asks — I'm talking about Lottie **Interactivity**, not Lottie Player.)

Comment: Looks like you have to listen for the load event, to create the animation [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c175bc5f1a044c17b1822b7784cd6a49?version=3.46.4)

Comment: ^ This is the answer! (Dunno how to mark it..)

Comment: Great the comment helped! :) I just added it as an answer ~ now you can mark it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have to listen for the load event to create the animation [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c175bc5f1a044c17b1822b7784cd6a49?version=3.46.4)

```
<script>
    import '@lottiefiles/lottie-player'
    import { create } from '@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity'

    function handleLoad(event) {
        create({
            mode: 'scroll',
            player: '#firstLottie',
            actions: [
                {
                    visibility: [0, 1],
                    type: 'seek',
                    frames: [0, 100],
                },
            ],
        });
    }
</script>

<div>   
    <lottie-player
        id="firstLottie"                     
        src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_i9mxcD.json"
        style="width:400px; height: 400px;"
        on:load={handleLoad}
    >
    </lottie-player>
</div>

<style>
    div {
        height: 2000px;
        padding-top: 500px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

During first page render it may say

> 500
> Internal Error

and it may show this error in the console: .

> ReferenceError: window is not defined

To eliminate this issue, we need to import the packages in onMount method. Here is the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/cef3be3518f94fb69474bddb028961fb?version=3.53.1)

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    onMount(async()=>{
        await import('@lottiefiles/lottie-player')
        // @ts-ignore
        const {create} = await import('@lottiefiles/lottie-interactivity')
        handleLoad(create) 
    })
    // @ts-ignore
    const handleLoad =  (method)=>{
        method({
            mode: 'scroll',
            player: '#firstLottie',
            actions: [
                {
                    visibility: [0, 1],
                    type: 'seek',
                    frames: [0, 500],
                },
            ],
        });
    }
</script>

<div> 
    <div style="height:400px"></div>  
    <lottie-player
        id="firstLottie"                     
        src="https://assets2.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_i9mxcD.json"
        style="width:400px; height: 400px;"
        on:load={handleLoad}
    >
    </lottie-player>
</div>
```